# PT100 at temperatures beyond the rated range

Tags: rtd, pt100

What happens if a PT100 such as the [P1K0.232.6W.B.010](https://www.ist-ag.com/sites/default/files/downloads/p1k0.232.6w.b.010.pdf) is exposed to higher temperatures, e.g. at 700°C instead of its rated upper limit of 600°C?

Does something destructive happen that damages the PT100 fast or over time or is just accuracy affected?

Is the highest temperature limit given by the sensing element itself or by its case or connection?

Comment: bad link ?? no result ...

Comment: corrected, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Hmmm ... from the datasheet it looks like long term stability might be affected at the maximum temperature, so one would assume at temperatures exceeding the maximum recommended, this will be even more adversely affected. It looks like the time spent at a particular temperature may also be an important factor. Probably best to check with IST directly as they would know exactly what the effect will be. Otherwise chose another similar component with higher temp ratings to allow for the extra margin you may expect.